# Playbooks applied to all boxes

Tags: azure, vagrant, ansible

My vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.define "master" do |node_dotnet|
    node_dotnet.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
          ....
      end
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook1.yml"
  end

  v1.times do |i|
    config.vm.define "random#{i}" do |nodes_py|
      nodes_py.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|  
          ....
      end
    end
    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook2.yml"
    end
  end
end
```

But both playbooks are being applied to all the boxes several times. ¿How to fix this?

So 2 problems, why are the playbooks applied several times, why are they being applied to all the boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined Ansible provider (two times) at the config level, so it's being applied to all machines.

<sup>It's even clear if you look at your indentation levels (although this is not relevant in the Vagrantfile).</sup>

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.define "master" do |node_dotnet|
    node_dotnet.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
          ....
      end
    node_dotnet.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook1.yml"
    end
  end

  v1.times do |i|
    config.vm.define "random#{i}" do |nodes_py|
      nodes_py.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|  
          ....
      end
      nodes_py.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "playbook2.yml"
      end
    end
  end
end
```